# Apache ServerAlias wildcard for domains (e.g. subdomain.*.com)

Tags: apache-2.2, serveralias

I know it's possible to use wildcards for subdomain aliases like:

```
ServerAlias *.domain.com
```

But is it possible to use that for *domains* having a the same subdomain?

```
# like this
ServerAlias subdomain.*.com
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that should work - the rules for wildcards in `ServerAlias` don't need to worry about the rules that DNS wildcards follow.